# Powershell, set path as an everyday autocreated folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that is created every morning and named as 'ddMMyy' (I know EU date formats are not powershell's best friend ...)

I'm trying to set a path in a script as the folder with the current date :

```
$date = Get-Date -Format ddMMyy
$root = "X:\test\$date"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -filter *.*
```

But the script keeps looking for files in the "test" folder and not the folder '190422'

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the rest of the code :

```
$date = Get-Date -Format ddMMyy
$root = "X:\test\$date"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -filter *.*

#Starting on Row 2
[int]$i = 2

ForEach ($file in $files){
   

#Client 
$cs = switch -Regex -File $file {
        # exit the switch if we reach a line with 'Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER'
        'Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER' { break }
        # parse the string into named matches
        '^(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<idleft>[^\s]+)\s+(?<idright>\d+)\s+(?<error>\d+)\s+(?<details>(.+))$' {
            # output an object with the wanted properties
            $st = '{0}-{1}' -f $matches['idleft'], $matches['idright']
           
    }
    }
$row = $i
$Column = 1
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column) = "$st"
```

and the error PS gives me :

```
Cannot find path 'X:\test\FILE.001' because it does not exist.
At X:\test\script.ps1:38 char:27
+ $cs = switch -Regex -File $file {
+                           ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (X:\test\FILE.001:String) [], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound"
```

Comment: are you SURE that the `$Root` dir is what you expect? \\\\\ and, yes, the bass-akwards EU format is every bit as foolish as the inside-out US format. use the sensible and sortable `yyyy-MM-dd` format instead.

Comment: That's the issue, I cannot change (and not allowed to) the folder name And yes the $root folder is "x:\test\190422" for today as an exemple

Comment: then you need to check  for things like permissions. it may be that the account you are using is not allowed to even see that dir. ///// other than that, i would try adding a `Test-Path` in there to see what is visible at that point for that account.

Comment: Well if you're not allowed to use a sane date format, that's hardly PowerShell's fault. And if your `$root` really is `x:\test\190422` and that folder exists, then your code works. If your code does not work, then either `$root` has a different value in reality, or your code is in reality different from what you're showing here.

Comment: the rest of the code is a Regex switch that goes through all the files in the $root folder then parses the result in an Excel column

Comment: I think it has something to do with my variable $files that is not clearing its content

Comment: Please check if the everyday-created folder is really using the year as two digits instead of what would be normal 4, and if indeed it uses a two-digit year, can you be sure the format is `ddMMyy` and not `yyMMdd` ? The code should work if you get that format right, although I would do `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter * -File` to avoid collecting DirectoryInfo objects as well..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cast the $root, why not do a Join-Path instead?

```
Join-Path -Path X:\test -ChildPath $date
```

This will ensure the slashes are aligned as well.

Also, I would suggest using a name other than $root - something like $SearchDir. This is because Root can have other meanings.

Comment: tried a simple command` $date = Get-Date -Format ddMMyy
$path = Join-Path -Path X:\New\status -ChildPath $date
cd $path` it works, but not in my code, seems to be an issue with switch -regex